# Linked List Type Error

Tags: python, linked-list, typeerror

I am a beginner and I started learning python programming and I am stuck with an error. I get a type error

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None
        self.next = Node

    def setData(self,data)
        self.data = data

    def getData(self):
        return self.data

    def setNext(self,next):
        self.next = next

    def getNext(self):
        return self.next

    def hasNext(self):
        return self.next!=None


class LinkedList(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.length = 0
        self.head = None

    def listLength(self):
        currentNode = self.head
        length = 0

        while currentNode.hasNext:
            length = length + 1
            currentNode = currentNode.getNext()
        return length

"""
Methods to Insert nodes in a Linked List:
# insertNode: Use this method to simply insert a node to the Linked List
# insertHead: Use this method to insert a node at the head of the Linked List
# insertTail: Use this method to insert a node at the tail of the Linked List
# insertAtPosition: Use this method to insert a node at a particular position of the Linked List
"""

    def insertNode(self,node):
        if self.length == 0:
            self.insertHead(node)
        else:
            self.insertTail(node)

    def insertHead(self, data):
        nodeToBeInserted = Node()
        nodeToBeInserted.setData(data)
        if self.length == 0:
            self.head = nodeToBeInserted
        else:
            nodeToBeInserted.setNext(self.head)
            self.head = nodeToBeInserted
        self.length = self.length + 1

    def insertTail(self,data):
        nodeToBeInserted = Node()
        nodeToBeInserted.setData(data)
        currentNode = self.head

        while currentNode.getNext() != None:
            currentNode = currentNode.getNext()
        currentNode.setNext(nodeToBeInserted)
        self.length = self.length + 1

    def insertAtPosition(self,data, position):
        if position > self.length or position < 0:
            print("Invalid position!, The size of the Linked List is:%s"%self.length)
        else:
            if position ==0:
                self.insertHead(data)
            else:
                nodeToBeInserted = Node()
                nodeToBeInserted.setData(data)
                currentNode = self.head
                count = 0
                while count < position - 1:
                    currentNode = currentNode.getNext()
                    count = count + 1
                nodeToBeInserted.setNext(currentNode.getNext())
                currentNode.setNext(nodeToBeInserted)
                self.length = self.length+1

ll = LinkedList()
ll.insertNode(1)
ll.insertNode(2)
ll.insertNode(3)
```

The error I am seeing is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/XPS 13/PycharmProjects/DataStructures/LinkedList/Implementation/SinglyLinkedList.py", line 154, in <module>
ll.insertNode(2)
  File "C:/Users/XPS 13/PycharmProjects/DataStructures/LinkedList/Implementation/SinglyLinkedList.py", line 92, in insertNode
self.insertTail(node)
  File "C:/Users/XPS 13/PycharmProjects/DataStructures/LinkedList/Implementation/SinglyLinkedList.py", line 121, in insertTail
while currentNode.getNext() != None:
TypeError: getNext() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

If someone can please explain me the reason for this error it will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You should use `x is not None` as opposed to `x!=None`.  See PEP 8 for more info.  http://pep8.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made mistakes in your code:

In `Node` class:

```
self.next = Node
```

Why do you make this statement? Assign class itself to next is unreasonable. it should be:

```
self.next = None
```

Another thing, I would like to suggest is you'd better design a good `__init__` function for each class. Think the `__init__` function in a class as a constructor for the class.

In your `__init__` function, no arguments are provided, which means when you instantiate the class, you cannot pass any data to it. In practice, we always need to provide some data to instantiate a class. Let's take the `Node` class for example, when we use it, we often already know the data this node should store, and the `next` node information, may or may not be known. So the better way to define its `__init__` function is:

```
def Node():
    def __init__(self, data, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next
```

Next time, you make new instance with `data` property known:

```
node = Node(data=1)
```

If you also know the `next` property:

```
node = Node(data=1, next=next)
```

This make you more convenient, without need to call `setX` function.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got a typo right here:

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None
        self.next = Node
```

That should be `self.next = None`.

The reason you're getting `getNext() missing 1 required positional argument` is because eventually `insertTail` reaches the end of the linked list, and the `Node` type is assigned to `currentNode`. So the next time you call `currentNode.getNext()`, you're actually calling `Node.getNext()`, which raises the error because there's no Node instance to implicitly assign to `self`.

Comment: in addition to this, there should be a colon in the definition for method setData(), though I assume it isn't in OPs post because of a copying error.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

`while currentNode.hasNext` is always true, because it is a method.

On the other hand, `while currentNode.hasNext()` might be false at some point.

---

`self.next = Node` means the class is next.

On the other hand, `self.next = Node()` would make a new instance.

But I guess you don't want that, because it would try to create an endless linked list, so `self.next = None` might be better.

This causes `currentNode = currentNode.getNext()` to assign the class to `currentNode` and then later, the next call to `currentNode.getNext()` is actually calling `Node.getNext()` which causes this error.